# how to get the value from href?

Tags: jquery

When a link is clicked, I need to transfer the first and last name from the href and then navigate to the next page. How do I do this?

**HTML**

```
<a href="candidate.cfm">
     #result.firstname# #result.lastname#
</a>
```

**JQuery:**

```
  $('a [name="submit1"]').click(function(event) {
      alert(#result.firstname#)
   });
```

Comment: <a href="candidate.cfm" name="submit1">

Comment: Please post the HTML that is rendered in the browser not the ColdFusion code here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('[name="submit1"]').click(function(event) {
      var names = $(this).text();
      });
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6FGqN/771/

Comment: thanks a lot we got the answer . if i have any doubt further shall i ask u

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the content within the tags by fetching the content with

> var content = $("a").contents();

And then you can easily alert the content by doing

> alert(content);

within your click function

If all you wanted was the text and you were not planning on adding any other tags within the  tag, this might work better

> var content = $("a").text();